# Can I use a namespaces in current_page method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want do add an active class to my menu if the current URL is part of a namespace, e.g. organization/clients. How can I achieve that? Are there any methods like `current_page?(:namespace => 'organization')` or something similar?

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :organization do
  resources :clients
  root to: 'dashboard#index'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something to the effect of:

```
current_page?(url_for(:controller => 'organizations', :action => 'index'))
```